# Prove that the chromatic number of a graph is the same as the maximum of the chromatic numbers its blocks.

Tags: graph-theory

Here's the statement to be proved:

> The chromatic number of a graph is the same as the maximum chromatic number of its blocks.

Here's what I think. We consider the graph $G$ with chromatic number $\chi(G)=k$. Let $\chi(B)$ be the maximum chromatic number of a block of $G$. Now, clearly $\chi(B) \leq k,$ since a block is a subgraph of $G.$ This would tell me that every individual block could be colored with at most $k$ colors.

Now,  any two blocks share at most one vertex, so intuitively it would make sense that we could find a proper coloration for  $G$ with at most $k$ colors, by picking the color of the common vertices in a clever way. But how can I prove this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of *block*? "A subgraph with as many edges as possible and no cut vertex (a vertex whose removal disconnects the subgraph)" ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My definition  of a block is a maximal nonseparable subgraph of a graph $G$. So yes, basically what you just said.

Comment: Years ago, I took a course in combinatorial algorithms where the book stated that this was obvious, and I don't think I ever figured out why.  Thanks for asking this question. +1

Comment: @saulspatz I'm glad my question has also helped others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block decomposition of a graph leads to a tree. Assume that all the blocks of $G$ have been colored but two blocks $B_1,B_2$ do not agree about the coloring of their common vertex.  Then by rotating/replacing the colors in one of the two blocks we may resolve such issue. Due to the tree-structure of the block decomposition, we may pick a block as "root"  and resolve all the color-conflicts, proceeding from the root to the leaves and fixing the colors of the children blocks each time.

Comment: +1 Would it also work to just color the blocks top-down in the tree?  If I'm not mistaken, no conflicts would arise.

Comment: @saulspatz: oh, sure, that is clearly more algorithmically efficient than coloring first and fixing it later.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What is still not so clear to me is how we can assure that we will _always_ be able to resolve the possible color conflicts that arise, could you tell me why that is?

Comment: @ThomasBladt: assume that the largest chromatic number of the blocks is $5$, such that each color is $\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Start by coloring the father block $B_1$ and the child block $B_2$. Assume that $B_1$ and $B_2$ intersect at a vertex which has color $1$ in the coloring of $B_1$ and color $2$ in the coloring of $B_2$. Adjust the coloring of $B_2$ via $1\to 5\to 4\to 3\to 2\to 1$ and there is no conflict anymore. Then adjust the coloring of all the children of $B_1$. Continue until all blocks have been colored with no conflicts.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I understand. But suppose you have a graph that consists of,say, 3 blocks. And imagine $B_1$ has a vertex  in common with $B_2$, and $B_2$ has some other vertex in common with $B_3$. Suppose that $B_1$ has no common vertex with $B_3$. Now we color all these blocks, as you say, and find that $B_1$, $B_2$ have a conflict with their common vertex. We can swap around colors in $B_2$ so we reach an agreement, but how does this assure me that such a coloration also works for the common vertex of $B_2$ and $B_3$?

Comment: @ThomasBladt: color $B_1,B_2,B_3$. Rotate the colors of $B_2$ in such a way that $B_1,B_2$ agree on the common vertex. Then rotate the colors of $B_3$ in such a way that $B_2,B_3$ agree on the common vertex. Top-down.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh, now I get it! That's what you meant when you said pick a root block. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you please explain by 'block decomposition of a graph leads to a tree' . I am unable to grasp this concept .