# help finding the chromatic number for a graph with two blocks as subgraphs that share a single vertex

Tags: graph-theory

$G$ is a graph with exactly two blocks $B_1$ and $B_2$. $B_1$ and $B_2$ share a single vertex. Can you express the chromatic number of $G$ as a function of the chromatic number of $B_1$ and $B_2$?

**Note:** it is not specified whether G is connected or not

Let $X(G)$ represent the chromatic number of $G$

I think the answer is: $X(G) \leq X(G - B1 - B2 ) + 2$

I got this because I am pretty sure that a graph that is just two blocks connected by a single vertex would have a chromatic number of $2$, so we remove $B_1$ and $B_2$ from $G$ and add back $2$.

here is another post from this website that will probably help: **[Prove that the chromatic number of a graph is the same as the maximum of the chromatic numbers its blocks.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739925/prove-that-the-chromatic-number-of-a-graph-is-the-same-as-the-maximum-of-the-chr)**

Comment: Two $K_3$ connected together via a single vertex is not 2 colorable?

Comment: @nafhgood  $K_3$ is 3-colourable, thus two $K_3$ connected by a single vertex is also 3-colourable.

Comment: So then it is not true that a graph with two blocks connected by a single vertex have chromatic number 2?

Answer (score 1):

We know that there cannot exist an edge from $B_1$ to $B_2$ as this form a cycle and $G$ would be 2-connected itself. By this, saying $G-B_1-B_2$ doesn't make much sense as it will be an empty graph.

We now note that $X(G)= \max \{X(B_1), X(B_2) \}$ as we can colour $B_1$ and $B_2$ independent of each other.